# Why is a assigned to l in every step of for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the code for sorting a list without any method.
I had entered a `print` statement in the `for` loop to print the values of `a` and `l`.

```
l,a=(input("enter terms separate with ','\n")).split(','),"5"
def so(m,n,b=0):
    try: return (so(m,n,b+1) if(m[b]==n[b]) else [m,n] if(ord(m[b])<ord(n[b])) else [n,m])
    except: return [m,n] if(b==len(m)) else [n,m]
while(a!=l):
    print(a," is assigned ",l)
    a=l
    for i in range((len(l)-1)):
        l[i],l[i+1]=so(l[i],l[i+1])[0],so(l[i],l[i+1])[1]
        print(l,i,a)
```

I accept that I have written `a=l` in the `while` loop, but the `while` loop is executed only once. I knew it by inserting a `print` statement inside the `while` loop.

After every step in the `for` loop, `a` has the same value as `l` which is not defined anywhere.
Also, I didn't assign `a` or `l` to any value in the function.

Comment: You *need* to write the code here, not in an image or a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while(a!=l):
    print(a," is assigned ",l)
    a=l
    for i in range((len(l)-1)):
        l[i],l[i+1]=so(l[i],l[i+1])[0],so(l[i],l[i+1])[1]
        print(l,i,a)
```

this is how it appears in my IDE.

when you write `a=l`, python does not create a new variable `a` and assign it values. it just creates a reference to `l`.

[you can check it here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rSMc.png)